# Compare two list based on condition C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is the point that I want to implement

1. Get TrackId by provided System Type (user input) and also keep note of the staging (user input (S,A,E,Q,P))
2. Query SID list by TrackId && InUse = false
3. Take result and access property Track e.g 0A
4. Check if there is any already existing SID which is InUse = true and has the same track "0A"
5. If yes -> start over in step 2 and add to condition is not "0A"

Here are the two method which return the list

```
var tracklist = _sidRepo.GetTrackSidList(request.systemType);// return point no 2
        var SidList = _sidRepo.GetAllList();// return the whole sid list
```

Now the question is I have list of Sid objects in tracklist , I want to check trackId property if its present in the second list with InUse property of second list is true, If its true I do not want to check it again and add condition that TrackId is check already and move on to next trackid from tracklist . Any idea?

Comment: I would take a look to Set [data structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/). If the two list consist of the same types and don't have duplicated items then Set might be a help in comparison.

Comment: Can you show us the structure of the SID class, and what's the second list? Maybe you can describe in details, or combine with an example to illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure what you want. But from what I understand you can try this

```
var tracklist = _sidRepo.GetTrackSidList(request.systemType);// return point no 2
var SidList = _sidRepo.GetAllList();// return the whole sid list
    
// Create a that will track if a trackId has already been checked
var trackIds = new List<int>();
var validTracks = new List<Sid>();

// we create a list of possible ids
var secondListIds = SidList.Select(x => x.TrackId);

// Loop through
foreach(var track in tracklist){

    // Check the exit condition
    if (trackIds.Contains(track.TrackId))
        continue;
        
    // Ok so we havn't seen this track ID before
    // We can check if it the Second list contains it
    if (secondListIds.Contains(track.TrackId))
        // It Does so we add it to the valid Track Ids
        validTracks.add(track);
        
    // Finally add the it to the check list     
    trackIds.Add(track.TrackId);
}
```

Comment: As a rule, do not use `List.Contains`. Use `Set` instead.

Comment: Or rather `HashSet`.